# append element to array using function in ExtJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, extjs

Guys I want to append element to array named drawnShapes in draw() function

and getDrawnShapesCount() should give the number of drawn shapes as explained

drawnShapes is the array

```
Ext.define('Shape', {

static: {
    drawnShapes: ['Shape1'],
    getDrawnShapesCount: function () {
        console.log('the number of drawn shapes is :' +this.drawnShapes.length);
    }
},
draw: function (newShape) {
    debugger;
    var newShape;
    this.drawnShapes[this.drawnShapes.length -1 ]=[newShape];
// I try push too and it doesn't work
// this.drawnShapes.push(newShape);
    console.log(newShape + 'is drawn....');
    console.log('the number of drawnShapes is ' + this.drawnShapes.length)
}, 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just use

`this.drawnShapes.push(newShape)`

I think if its not working its because you have an un-instantiated var newShape.  It's just an empty variable declared right before you try to push it.  You can't push nothing onto an array.  Unless you're not showing us all the code.  Try

`/* REMOVE THIS var newShape; */
this.drawnShapes.push(newShape);`

So you can let newShape come in as an argument.  The declaration just overwrites the argument.

Comment: var new shape should be set when call draw method from the object
so suppose we have object called shape1
      `shape1.draw('rectangle')`

Comment: Right, so within the `draw()` method, `newShape` would be `=='rectangle'` except right before you push it on the array you erase it with `var newShape`.  You don't need to declare `newShape` if its already declared as a parameter of the method, you're just overwriting/erasing it, then you are pushing nothing onto the array.